# how to generate one commit out of git diff

Tags: git

Is there a way to generate one `commit` that contains the code changes between two branches? I have a branch and I committed too many times with short messages, and then I merged the latest state of master into it. Now I want to put all the changes into one single commit with one single commit message and push to remote. It seems interactive `rebase` will not work because I merged master into my branch at last ...

When I do this: `git diff master..mybranch`, I see the changes that I want to put into a new commit!

Comment: Try to Squash Commits as described here http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use interactive rebase, just start at `master` and squash all the commits into a single one.

Alternatively, you can also use the output of that diff to generate a patch and then apply that patch using `git apply`:

```
git diff master..mybranch > patch
git checkout master
git apply patch
```

Afterwards, add your changes and commit them as a single commit.